# jQuery ajax - pass multiple parameters via GET

Tags: c#, jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an ajax method to retrieve a partial view based on a filter criteria using GET. However, it seems that I'm not able to pass in more than one parameter unless their all primitive types. No errors are thrown, just are passed in as `null`.

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'json',
    contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8',
    url: '/DataManagement/GetDataPartialView',
    data: { configFilter : filter, Name: "SomeValue"},
    success: function (data) {
       $('#divManagement').html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Failed...');
    }
});
```

Controller

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult GetDataPartialView(ConfigFilter configFilter, string Name)
{
    ....
    return PartialView("_DataPartialView.tmpl", model);
}
```

Model

```
public class ConfigFilter
{
    public string ConnectionString { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string AppKey { get; set; }
}
```

if I pass either, it works... But I need to pass in both parameters.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to change the data object your passing to relate to the models/parameters in your method

```
$.ajax({
    cache: false,
    type: "GET",
    dataType: 'html', // your returing a view
    // contentType: 'application/json, charset=utf-8', remove
    url: '@Url.Action("GetDataPartialView", "DataManagement")', // don't hard code
    data: { ConnectionString: 'xxx', UserId: 'xxx', AppKey: 'xxx', Name: 'xxx' },
    success: function (data) {
       $('#divManagement').html(data);
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        alert('Failed...');
    }
});
```

Note aslo that your method is returning html, not json

Comment: Is that way no need to change the controller's overload? public ActionResult GetDataPartialView(ConfigFilter configFilter, string Name)

GetDataPartialView need ConfigFilter object instead of primitive types.

Comment: @toha, No there is no need to change the method. The `DefaultModelBinder` reads the posted data and matches anything in the method parameters, including properties in a model.